Google Mesh Wi-Fi pucks won't connect
For reference, this is my system. I do not have a separate Google Nest base unit, as is apparently common; just the pucks. They've worked well in the past; this is a new problem.
I've been having intermittent connection issues after a family member dropped the base puck (the one connected to the modem) while reorganizing. As a result, I decided to try switching it out with one of the satellites.
The replacement kept going in a cycle of solid dark blue -> no light -> pulsing dark blue -> slowly strobing orange/yellow light and wouldn't connect to the Internet, so I performed a network reset in the Google Home app. This did not appear to have any effect.
I then tried reconnecting the original base puck. It successfully booted up and is providing wireless Internet; however, none of the pucks will connect to it, instead displaying a sequence of solid dark blue -> nothing -> flashing dark blue -> pulsing amber and refusing to connect to the base puck. I have tried unplugging them and then plugging them back in, to no avail.
I have also tried running mesh tests in the Google Home app; it failed with the message,

Mesh test failed
Make sure your Wifi router is plugged in

How do I get my mesh network working again?

I am pretty sure the base unit and the other units are NOT interchangeable

@Ramhound They all look the same: round white pucks/columns with an LED ring in the center

@Ramhound https://www.amazon.ca/Google-Whole-Wi-Fi-System-Version/dp/B01MAW2294

You reset each of the devices? Since your changing which one is the primary unit, I would reset the entire set, and go through the setup process you originally followed when you got them
